# What is the data usage of Splatoon 2 online?

Tags: splatoon-2

My SO wants to play Splatoon on the go (when she is on break at work) but doesn't have access to a Wifi Hotspot.

She was thinking of using her phone's 3G network as a Wifi Hotspot so she could play Splatoon 2 online.

But how much data does Splatoon 2 consume, let's say, per hour of play?

PS: Also, if you try it to see how much it consumes, is the lag ok when playing on a 3G Network?

Comment: While not exactly your situation, I wondered the same about WoW before. Heaviest data usage I've personally seen was about 32kb/s, and an average of about 12 kb/s. Surely Splatoon with a max of 8 players per match can't be too much more. Let's say it uses 15 kb/s, that makes about 52mb/h.

Comment: Personally I would hesitate doing any "real-time" gameplay on a 3G network... but that's my opinion.

Comment: A venturebeat article say the test they did in March used 150mb for an hour and that it was smooth on LTE. I didn't find anything about 3G though.

Comment: In March? Probably talking about the switch playing by itself because I'm pretty sure there were no launch online multiplayer games out (or with review copies available). Arms was still a long way out and I think thats the first with online realtime multiplayer.

Comment: @Fredy31 [source](https://venturebeat.com/2017/03/25/splatoon-2-uses-about-150mb-of-mobile-data-per-hour-while-tethering/) for the test statement. Looks like a beta test of some sort.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [one article](https://venturebeat.com/2017/03/25/splatoon-2-uses-about-150mb-of-mobile-data-per-hour-while-tethering/), they used their phone as a hotspot and found that it used about **150Mb of data an hour.** (actually 153 to be more precise).

[A Redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/6oy7b8/splatoon_2_uses_about_150_mb_an_hour_of_data/) reported yesterday (July 23, 2017) a few sources stating about 135-160Mb an hour.  It appears that you can expect about this much data to be used an hour.

Comment: @Fredy31, I'm not sure what you are looking for in regards to the lag part of your question. Can you clarify? I'll try and answer that bit as well.

Comment: I think they're looking for how the connection is compared to say home wifi or something more consistent/reliable than a phone's 3G.

Comment: @n_palum probably - I was thinking more in terms on how it would impact the data usage, but that makes sense.

Comment: @TimmyJim The usual that would make a game unplayable if the internet is bad; Lag, Bad Ping, Getting dropped, etc.

Comment: @Fredy31 I would say that on a 4G connection you should be fine.  A strong 3G connection should suffice as well, but your mileage may vary depending on signal strength.  4G is comparable (at times) to wired and wireless connections, but obviously signal strengths will play a big role.

Comment: People have been suggesting you can play this game on a potato and have no lag. It's apparently very impressive in that regard!

Comment: @Fredy31 it also depends if the 3G network you're on is CDMA or GSM. CDMA is considerably slower. Different carriers will have different connection qualities, too. The only way to know for sure is to try it.